# Augmenting nested properties in TypeScript module augmentation

Tags: typescript, module-augmentation

I have 3 files in the same directory: `usage.ts`, `animal.types.d.ts` and `augment-animal.d.ts`:

`usage.ts` file:

```
import './augment-animal.types';
import { Animal } from './animal.types';

const animal: Animal['Schemas']['Dog'] = {
  id: 'someId',
  name: 'someName' // <------ throws an error because Dog doesn't have such property
}
```

`animal.types.d.ts`

```
export interface Animal {
  Schemas: {
    Dog: {
      id: string;
    };
  }
}
```

`augment-animal.types.d.ts`

```
declare module './animal.types' {
  interface Animal {
    topLevelProperty: string, // <--- it works
    Schemas: {
      Dog: {
        name: string; // <--- it doesn't work
      };
    }
  }
}
```

How I can augment nested properties using TypeScript module augmentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems there:

1. Order of imports matters: in particular, an interface imported later augments one imported earlier, so I would have expected `"animal.types.d.ts"` imported *before* `"augment-animal.d.ts"`, since the latter, by the name of it, is the one meant to augment the former.
2. You are allowed in TS to *augment* existing interfaces, not change what is already there (somewhat ambiguously the docs talk of interfaces being "extendable", anyway it is about *augmentation*): https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces

> How I can augment nested properties using TypeScript module augmentation?

So, the short answer to that question is *you cannot*.  All you can do is define a *new* interface or type that *extends* the given one.

Here is some example code inspired by yours that should make all of the above clearer:

```
// Uncomment to see the errors:

export interface Animal {  // "first import"
  id: string;
  schema: { name: string };
}

export interface Animal {  // "augmentation"
  //id: number;  // ERROR: cannot redefine `id`!
  schema: {      // ERROR: cannot redefine `schema`!
    name: string;
    //title: string;
  };
  name: string;  // OK: `Animal` can be augmented
}

const animal: Animal = {
  id: 'someId',
  name: 'someName',
  schema: { name: 'name' },
};

export interface Animal2 extends Animal {  // "extension"
  schema: {
    //name: number;  // ERROR: 'Animal2' incorrectly extends 'Animal'
    name: "NAME";  // OK: (sub-)property type narrowing, if one wants
    title: string;  // OK: new (sub-)property
  };
  anything?: unknown;  // OK: new property
}

const animal2: Animal2 = {
  id: 'someId',
  name: 'someName',
  schema: {
    name: "NAME",
    title: "title",
  },
};
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#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-K4oFS+Fz9VQ2COp3Ol325mK4azSFzoCjMYTSdgKY0Tssdxk9SdqAIpgA-AYYpAANaNXOQUNvT7N1tdntpqF0WHw+phK3IhUS9GSTH6HF45BE+nbFnnml0skyNYjHg68ZZ2-yf1B+SP8Y1x55AA39+y5CwgA)